# Sums of Two Real Powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find the nontrivial solutions for $m_{1}^{\theta}+n_{1}^{\theta}=m_{2}^{\theta}+n_{2}^{\theta}$
where $m_{1},m_{2},n_{1},n_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{R}_{>1}$.

1. If $\theta$ is a sufficient large integer, how to check the pairs
   $\left(m_{1},n_{1}\right)$ and $\left(m_{2},n_{2}\right)$ meets
   the equation above? Can I put $m_{1},m_{2},n_{1},n_{2}$ into some
   group $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ and use Euler's function to get some $\theta'<\theta$
   which can return the same result as $\theta$? If not, what is the best algorithm to check this so far?
2. How to generalize the equation if $\theta$ is irrational?

Comment: Showing they exist may be possible, finding them not as easy.  For e.g., WLOG, we may restrict to $m_i  \ge n_i$. Further, if $m_1 > m_2$ and  $m_1+n_1 < m_2+n_2$ there is always a solution for $\theta \in \mathbb R_{>1}$, from continuity and the limit as $\theta \to \infty^+$.

Comment: It is not known whether there are any nontrivial integer solutions to $a^5+b^5=c^5+d^5$. It is widely believed that there aren't any